# How does ps measure %CPU per process (and can this be changed?)

Tags: cpu, ps

When doing `ps -r -e -o pcpu=,comm=`, the % CPU displayed per process, over how long time is this value measured? Is it one second? The manual page does not seem to mention this.

And a follow-up question: Is it possible to have `ps` (or another standard UNIX utility) report the CPU percentage per process over a longer period of time, like 5 seconds? (Obviously, one could just gather up 5 values and calculate the average, but I'm not sure if that would even be correct
...)

PS! If it matters, I'm on macOS (which runs a BSD variant).

Comment: I don't think `ps` measures anything, it just reports the information that the kernel gives it.

Comment: @Kusalananda: So this happens on quite a low level, then. I'd be interested in hearing a bit more from someone who knows the UNIX kernel and how this is calculated. At least if I'm going to calculate averages over time, I need to know if the straight-forward method will give a correct representation.

Comment: Note that `ps` is not actually a standard Unix utility, so you probably want to say what Unix system you are running on if you want to know about how `ps` queries for the information that it shows.

Answer (score 5):

For PS the percent CPU is based on the lifetime of the process. Basically (user time + system time) / (now - process start time).

So 5% means the process has been bothering the CPU 5% of the time it has been alive.

Top does it differently, it's based on the refresh time of top. So most of the time these numbers will not match.

Comment: Are you sure about this...? I tried this now by starting an intense `ffmpeg` process which takes 100%. If I put it to the background after 10 seconds, `ps` drops to 0 almost immediately, whereas if it calculated an average over its lifespan like you suggest, displayed CPU% would have dropped gradually. I did: `while true; do ps -e -o pcpu,comm | grep ffmpeg; sleep 1; done`